# JavaScript AppendChild display for a short moment before being reset

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I am trying to insert some HTML data into a div tag using a hyperlink that calls a Javascript function upon clicking on the hyperlink.

The HTML data works and the items I am it to show up appears but it disappears immediately after executing.

I have tried event.preventDefault() which works on Chrome based browsers but does not work on Firefox. I have tried 'return false' at the end of the Javascript function but it doesn't work.

The code is below:

```html
<div id="doHere"></div>
<p>Toggle <a href="" onclick="toggle()">HERE</a> !!!</p>
<script>
  function toggle() {
    // event.preventDefault(); // Does not work on Firefox
    document.getElementById('doHere').innerHTML = '<ol><li> Test test </li></ol>';
    // return false; // Not working on both Chrome and Firefox
  }
</script>
```

How do I ensure that the edited HTML is permanent ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with "#" value for `href`

```html
<div id="doHere"></div>
<p>Toggle <a href="#" onclick="toggle()">HERE</a> !!!</p>
<script>
  function toggle() {
    // event.preventDefault(); // Does not work on Firefox
    document.getElementById('doHere').innerHTML = '<ol><li> Test test </li></ol>';
    // return false; // Not working on both Chrome and Firefox
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `javascript:void(0);` in `href` attribute:

```html
<html>
    <body>      
        <div id="doHere"></div>        
        <p>Toggle <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle()">HERE</a> !!!</p>        
        <script>
            function toggle() {
                document.getElementById('doHere').innerHTML = '<ol><li> Test test </li></ol>';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```